# When to dynamically change Validators to avoid Error: NG0100

Tags: angular

I followed Angular tutorial to create dynamic forms (https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form) and it work fine.
What I want to do now is to have a form with several questions with radio input choices (Yes/No). Depending on your previous choice, the form update itself and display the next question, and so making it as required.
My function show, inside the QuestionComponent, not only tell if the Question can be displayed but also reset the Validators, making it required or not.

```
show(): boolean {
    if (!isPreviousInputCheckedToNo()) {
      this.form.controls[this.question.key].clearValidators();
      this.form.controls[this.question.key].updateValueAndValidity();
      return false;
    } else if (this.question.required) {
      this.form.controls[this.question.key].setValidators([Validators.required]);
      this.form.controls[this.question.key].updateValueAndValidity();
    }
    return true;
  }
```

```
<div *ngIf="this.show()" [formGroup]="form">
  <label [attr.for]="question.key">{{question.label}}</label>

  <div [ngSwitch]="question.controlType">

    <input *ngSwitchCase="'textbox'" [formControlName]="question.key"
           [id]="question.key" [type]="question.type">

    <select *ngSwitchCase="'dropdown'" [id]="question.key" [formControlName]="question.key">
      <option *ngFor="let opt of question.options" [value]="opt.value">{{opt.label}}</option>
    </select>

    <input *ngSwitchCase="'number'" [formControlName]="question.key"
           [id]="question.key" [type]="question.type">

    <div *ngSwitchCase="'radio'">
      <label *ngFor="let opt of question.options" [attr.for]="question.key + opt.value">
        <input type="radio" [id]="question.key + opt.value"
               [value]="opt.value" [formControlName] = "question.key">
        {{opt.label}}</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It actually works. When I checked the radio button to No, the next input is displayed and made required.
But I have angular throwing me this error :

> ERROR Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value for 'disabled': 'false'. Current value: 'true'.. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0100

I would like to understand why it happens and how to avoid this error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well for what I understood (thanks to this https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-debugging/) it was due to a change of state (the validators) while angular is preparing the view to be displayed.
So we need to change those validators later, like at the next frame. Using SetTimeout isn't the most appealing solution but it was also the easiest.

This is what I did:

```
show(): boolean {
    if (this.question.showif !== '' && !eval("this.form.controls." + this.question.showif)) {
      if (this.isShown) {// this is to avoid setTimeout to be called at every frame
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.form.controls[this.question.key].clearValidators();
          this.form.controls[this.question.key].updateValueAndValidity();
        });
      }
      this.isShown = false;
      return false;
    } else if (this.question.required) {
      if (!this.isShown) {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.form.controls[this.question.key].setValidators([Validators.required]);
          this.form.controls[this.question.key].updateValueAndValidity();
        });
      }
    }
    this.isShown = true;
    return true;
  }
```

This is not the pretiest but it works like a charm